# Angular 8 to 11 Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8, angular11, angular-upgrade

Have had an angular v8 app running for over a year with no issues.

Have upgraded the app to v11 (11.2.13). However, on first npm start (which calls serve), i get the following error in my cmd line:

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

If I comment out a line, a space, make any change, to any file the cli/cmd line then updates and continues to serve as expected.

Having tried to wipe out most of my code, I have located the issue down to a local lib module. However, even when i export a lib with nothing in the `Max call stack` error displays again.

Oddly, this error has only appeared since upgrading these lines:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.29",
"@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "^0.803.29"
```

to
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.12",
"@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.901.12"

If I downgrade the v901 from above to 803 the issue goes away. However, upon loading the browser, I see error:

```
ReferenceError: __importDefault is not defined
```

Comment: It is the [same](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/issues/1289) issue you are getting? You can also add the error stack for more info.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara - sounds similar, but not using calendar in my app.

Comment: its not about the calendar. There is something which breaks when you upgrade and keep calling itself and making the stack full. The error stack trace might help to know the source. Also, check your Node version. You must have deleted the node_modules and resinstalled it?